# GroupBy date with ionic 2

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

In this view of the mobile application I need to group the data that are returned by json api group by date !!
how to groupby date the data json api with ionic 2 
!
In this view of the mobile application I need to group the data that are returned by json api group by date !!
how to groupby date the data json api with ionic 2 
!
Json API :

```
course_cheval: [
{
CourseHasCheval: {
id: "1461",
course_id: "460",
cheval_id: "90",
rang: "2",
temps: "TETE",
jockey_id: "30",
poids: "57",
part_jokey: "367.000",
entraineur_id: "6",
part_entraineur: "440.000",
propritaire: "GHARBI. MED",
part_propritaire: "4400.000",
eleveur_id: "47",
part_eleveur: "2200.000"
},
Course: {
id: "460",
date: "2012-06-24",
nom_du_prix: "GODOLPHIN ARABIAN",
allocation: "20000",
hippodrome_id: "2",
jouree: "36",
categorie_id: "1",
distance: "1600",
},
{
CourseHasCheval: {
id: "1412",
course_id: "445",
cheval_id: "90",
rang: "1",
temps: "1.53''8/10",
jockey_id: "3",
poids: "56",
part_jokey: "660.000",
entraineur_id: "6",
part_entraineur: "660.000",
propritaire: "GHARBI. MED",
part_propritaire: "6600.000",
eleveur_id: "47",
part_eleveur: "3300.000"
},
Course: {
id: "445",
date: "2012-10-21",
nom_du_prix: "RIDHA BEN EZZEDINE",
allocation: "12000",
hippodrome_id: "2",
jouree: "49",
categorie_id: "2",
distance: "1600",
nbre_partant: "9",
}
}]
```

[image: View ionic]

```
 <ion-grid *ngSwitchCase="'Compteurs'">



   <ion-row *ngFor="let m of members ">
        <ion-col width-20 >
        {{m.Course.date | date : "yyyy"}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-30>
        {{m.Course.nom_du_prix}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-20>
            GR.{{m.Course.categorie_id}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-30>
          {{m.Course.allocation}}
        </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array has some objects without a `date` property which complicates this slightly so lets start with a simpler example where everything has a `date` property like so

```
[
  {
    "name": "Philosophy 212: Ethics and Applications",
    "date": "2007-12-12"
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaScript Fundamentals",
    "date": "2007-12-12"
  },
  {
    "name": "Math 364: Linear Algebra",
    "date": "2017-01-15"
  }
]
```

We can write a `groupByDate` function that handles the basic case

```
function groupByDate<T extends {date: string}>(datedValues: T[]) {
  return datedValues.reduce((groups, dated) => {
    const key = dated.date;
    if (groups[key]) {
      groups[key].push(dated);
    } else {
      groups[key] = [dated];
    }
    return groups;
  }, {} as {[key string]: T[]});
}
```

Here it is in a snippet (sans types)

```js
var courses = [
  {
    "name": "Philosophy 212: Ethics and Applications",
    "date": "2007-12-12"
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaScript Fundamentals",
    "date": "2007-12-12"
  },
  {
    "name": "Math 364: Linear Algebra",
    "date": "2017-01-15"
  }
];

function groupByDate(datedValues) {
      return datedValues.reduce((groups, dated) => {
        const key = dated.date;
        if (groups[key]) {
          groups[key].push(dated);
        } else {
          groups[key] = [dated];
        }
        return groups;
      }, {});
    }

console.log(groupByDate(courses));
```

we can make this much more useful with by writing a more generic `groupBy` function that groups by any `string` value.

```
function groupBy<T>(values: T[], keyOrKeySelector: keyof T | ((value: T) => string)) {
  return values.reduce((groups, value) => {
    const key = typeof keySelector === 'function'
      ? keyOrKeySelector(value)
      : value[keyOrKeySelector];

    if (groups[key]) {
      groups[key].push(value);
    } else {
      groups[key] = [value];
    }
    return groups;
  }, {} as {[key string]: T[]});

  });
}
```

Either of these can be made into a pipe with minimal effort if you want to use them inside of an angular template.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Are you saying that given the example input it doesn't produce the correct output?

Comment: yes , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919676/calculating-sum-of-elements-by-date-in-angular-2-and-ionic-2-ngfor

Comment: So you asked the same question again?

Comment: No, this time I need to calculate the allocation by date

Comment: That's the same question. You would just aggregate after grouping. Also, you did not answer my question as to why this solution does not work for you.

Comment: I had some typos in my code. I added a snippet to demonstrate that it works as well.

Comment: I do not know, but for now I need to calculate the allocations by date, as stated in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919676/calculating-sum-of-elements-by-date-in-angular-2-and-ionic-2-ngfor

Comment: `var byDate = groupByDate(courses); Object.keys(byDate).map(k => ({ date: k, allocations: byDate[k].reduce((s, n) => s + Number(n.allocations), 0) }))`

Comment: Thank you for your advancement, I am already group date, just I need to calculate the allocation when looping the data according to the date
Which is I explained well in the other question and  thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. There's more than enough here to do what you need.

Comment: I explain my need well ,

Comment: @MhdAmine in my comment I use `reduce` to calculate the sum of the allocations in each group. Is there any reason you can't do that too? That's also what the answer to your question does. Programming involves composing techniques into solution to a particular problem.

Comment: You are not well understood my needs

Comment: You also asked http://stackoverflow.com/q/43917449/1915893 and received [this correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43918359/1915893). Why have you not accepted it?

Comment: this answer  Allow it to calculate all allocations

Comment: Based on the comments, you did not initially ask that. But if you use the generic `groupBy` function in this answer, you can group by anything you wish. Put them together.

Comment: In the first comment I said that I need to calculate the allocations by date
And your function does not work

Comment: This question says "How to group by date?" I demonstrate that. There were a few typos. They are now fixed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917449/calculating-sum-of-elements-in-angular-2-and-ionic-2-ngfor : Well, here is my question you can help me?

Comment: You have at least 4 duplicates of this question.

Comment: please help me !!

Comment: As far as I am concerned, this answers your question. When asked for more information, you said _"I explain my need well"_. I disagree. You refuse to explain _how_ the answers you receive do not work and instead just say _"do not work"_.